# what does " python manage.py migrate " in django do exactly?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django, and the tutorial directly applied this command without explanation.

After searching, I found out it's calling migrations in Django, but didn't understand it either as I am a complete newbie at this.

What does the `python manage.py migrate` command do exactly?
What are migrations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Django's migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784533/what-is-djangos-migration)

Answer (score 6):

If your database doesn't exist yet, `migrate` creates all the necessary tables to match your model definitions.

Otherwise if the database already exists, `migrate` updates the existing table definitions to match the model definitions -- i.e. maybe you added a field to one of your models, so `migrate` would add that column to the database table.